# React Native onStartShouldSetResponder and onResponderRelease?

Tags: ios, button, reactjs, react-native

I've created a button that I want to have call a function on click and then again on release. A normal TouchableOpacity or other will trigger a function upon release of a click only, I need functions on both click AND release.

```
<View
    style={styles.touchbutton}
    onStartShouldSetResponder={() => this.clickOn()}
    onResponderRelease={() => this.clickRelease()}>
    <Text style={styles.dark}>Button</Text>
</View>
```

The above code works on click but not on release. I also tried onResponderReject but that doesn't work either. Hard to find what the command should be.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem. `onStartShouldSetResponder` needs to return `true`.

```
onStartShouldSetResponder={(e) => {
    /*do whatever*/;
    return true
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Try This code For your click event it works for me :

```
clickOn(){
Alert.alert(
  'Test Demo',
  'Please Enter Valid Data',
  [
    //{text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
)
  }
}
```

###### Put these two lines it works for me when you release

```
  onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
  onResponderRelease={() => this.onRowTap()}
```