# How do I disable the touch of a child element in Touchable Component

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have following code

```
<BlurView blurType={'light'} blurAmount={10} style={{flex: 1}}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={() => this.setState({displayVideoModal: false})}>
        <View style={{width: moderateScale(300), height: moderateScale(300), backgroundColor: '#333333', borderRadius: moderateScale(24)}}>

        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</BlurView>
```

Which result in following

[image]

I have TouchableOpacity covering the BlurView area because I want the full blur view screen to respond to touch event and hide it. except the view in the center. It will contain the video and must not receive the touch event of its parent component and it must have touch event of its own.

How do I do this? Or I am willing to know if there are alternatives to achieve the similar result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720039/can-i-disable-a-view-component-in-react-native

Comment: Not working, it still executes the parent on touch

Comment: `pointerEvents='box-none'' - The View is never the target of touch events but it's subviews can be, for further details https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view

Comment: Tried and still does not work, I am thinking If I can detect which view was touched wether parent or child then I can have a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nested Touchable seems to work in my case.

```
<BlurView blurType={'light'} blurAmount={10} style={{flex: 1}}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={() => this.setState({displayVideoModal: false})}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{width: moderateScale(300), height: moderateScale(300), backgroundColor: '#333333', borderRadius: moderateScale(24)}}>
            <View></View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</BlurView>
```

When I click on child `TouchableHighlight` it seems to receive the child touch event and ignore parent. This seems to work for now, not sure if it is the good option, will be open to hear for better options.

I also found this

[How can I propagate touch event in nested Touchable in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835883/how-can-i-propagate-touch-event-in-nested-touchable-in-react-native)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system

[React Native onStartShouldSetResponder and onResponderRelease?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758659/react-native-onstartshouldsetresponder-and-onresponderrelease)

Answer (score 8):

You can leverage [pointerEvents](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents):

```
<BlurView blurType={'light'} blurAmount={10} style={{flex: 1}}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={() => this.setState({displayVideoModal: false})}>
        <View pointerEvents="none" style={{width: moderateScale(300), height: moderateScale(300), backgroundColor: '#333333', borderRadius: moderateScale(24)}}>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</BlurView>
```

Comment: Sadly not working. It still execute the parent on touch

Comment: It will execute the parent on touch. Your question says you want to exclude the `View` from receiving the touch event `I want the full blur view screen to respond to touch event and hide it. except the view in the center.`

Comment: pointerEvents is not disabling the touch when I click on center view.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Simple and answered the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Nested touchables were not working for me because I also had buttons in the floating view. On the background overlay view (BlurView in this case), add the following props:

```
onStartShouldSetResponder={(event) => {
    return event.nativeEvent.touches.length == 1;
}}
onResponderRelease={(event) => {
    if (event.target == event.currentTarget) {
        this.props.onCancel()
    }
}}
```

This works because `event.currentTarget` is the view that has the prop `onResponderRelease` and `target` is the view that the touch was released upon.

React Native Gesture Responder System documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system